# PHP Date Issue with Excel Sheet

Tags: php

I am trying to convert an old office excel sheet document data into PHP web based app for searching and other data analysis. Stuck in how to fields called start_date & end_date. This tells me that if project is active or not. Data saved in below format. It compares both dates and return the project status by comparing with current date.

```
Start_Date  End Date  Status
1-Jan-16    31-Dec-16  Active or not
```

I tried with PHP date("Y-m-d") function but month is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function on your excel derived dates and then convert it to a usable DateTime value using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) like so:

```
$time_before = strtotime('1-Jan-16');
$date_before = date('Y-m-d', $time_before); // 2016-01-01

$time_after  = strtotime('31-Dec-16');
$date_after  = date('Y-m-d', $time_after); // 2016-12-31
```

Then [compare the two dates against each other](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).